# Input value not changed immediately after one click - PHP, AJAX, JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have code like this:

index.php file

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$databasename="admin_example";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $databasename);
$select = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM rating");
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);

if( $connect -> connect_error){
   echo ("connection failed" . $connection->connect_error);
}

function query($query){
    global $connect;
  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $rows = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $rows[] = $row;
  
    }
    return $rows;
  }

if(isset($_POST['like'])){
    global $connect, $select;

    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE rating SET total_votes=total_votes+1,likes=likes+1");
  
    foreach($select as $row){
        $likes = $row["likes"];

        echo $likes;
        exit();
      }
}

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rating_style.css">

<input type="button" id="like" onclick="like();" value="Likes: <?php echo $data["likes"]; ?>">


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

function like(){
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'index.php',
          data: {
            like:"likes"
          },
          success: function (response) {
            $("#like").prop('value', 'Likes: ' + response);
          }
    });
    }


</script>

<?php



?>
```

Its weird, the value not changed immediately. So, for example Likes: 0, you click once not changed still Likes: 0, click again Likes: 1, and then if I refresh browser the Likes: 2. I already search the answer on internet but no luck. Any help is appreciated, Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given example **"global $connect, $select;"** imports the select from global to local scope and it is executed before the rating update. So it is always returning the data before update.

The below code will gives you the expected behivour

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$databasename="admin_example";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $databasename);
$select = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM rating");
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);

if( $connect -> connect_error){
   echo ("connection failed" . $connection->connect_error);
}

function query($query){
    global $connect;
  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $rows = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $rows[] = $row;
  
    }
    return $rows;
  }

if(isset($_POST['like'])){
    global $connect, $select;

    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE rating SET total_votes=total_votes+1,likes=likes+1");
    //which should be executed after the update
    $select = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM rating");
    foreach($select as $row){
        $likes = $row["likes"];

        echo $likes;
        exit();
      }
}

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rating_style.css">

<input type="button" id="like" onclick="like();" value="Likes: <?php echo $data["likes"]; ?>">


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

function like(){
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'index.php',
          data: {
            like:"likes"
          },
          success: function (response) {
            $("#like").prop('value', 'Likes: ' + response);
          }
    });
    }


</script>

<?php



?>
```